# What's the convention for code lines with comments?

Tags: go, code-formatting

The Go model of code formatting conventions is "`gofmt` *is* the convention". There is one part of that convention I'm having difficulty in understanding, and it would be great to have a formal definition of which `gofmt` is an implementation, rather than having to deduce the model from empirical examples. Here's a sample.

Before `go fmt`:

```
func sieve(mine int,                  // This instance's own prime
           inch chan int,             // Input channel from lower primes
           done chan int,             // Channel for signalling shutdown
           count int) {               // Number of primes - counter
    start := true                     // First-number switch
    ouch := make(chan int)            // Output channel, this instance
    fmt.Printf("%v ", mine)           // Print this instance's prime
```

After `go fmt`:

```
func sieve(mine int, // This instance's own prime
    inch chan int, // Input channel from lower primes
    done chan int, // Channel for signalling shutdown
    count int) { // Number of primes - counter
    start := true                                 // First-number switch
    ouch := make(chan int)                        // Output channel, this instance
    fmt.Printf("%v ", mine)                       // Print this instance's prime
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? That is, why have some comments been detrimentally compressed, and others expanded? Some theories:

- This is so ugly it must mean that code without comments on the same line is preferred
- There's a bug in `gofmt`
- Incomplete (in some way) lines are treated differently from complete one
- Something else?

Comment: Usually, comment lines are preferred above the commented portion of code. Be aware, however, that comment blocks right before `package`, type and func declarations will show up in godoc. For license headers, leave a blank line between the header and the package godoc comment.

Comment: Seems like if your line is longer than a certain number of characters it will be indented to the right, otherwise it's appended right after the line...

Comment: Highly recommended official blog post: [Godoc: documenting Go code](http://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code)

Answer (score 6):

Conventionally, arguments are described in the function/method documentation. Consider [`math/big.(*Int).Exp` docs](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.5/src/math/big/int.go#L405):

```
// Exp sets z = x**y mod |m| (i.e. the sign of m is ignored), and returns z.
// If y <= 0, the result is 1 mod |m|; if m == nil or m == 0, z = x**y.
// See Knuth, volume 2, section 4.6.3.
func (z *Int) Exp(x, y, m *Int) *Int {
```

The main comment explains what `x`, `y` and `m` are and the relationships between them. [This](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Exp) is how it looks rendered by godoc.

Same for code, each line usually has its own comment line:

```
// First-number switch.
start := true
// Output channel, this instance.
ouch := make(chan int)
// Print this instance's prime.
fmt.Printf("%v ", mine)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this is clearly not the correct forum, just for the record I think your second case obscures, rather than enhances, the understandability of the code. (:-)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough that is the whole point of go fmt.  What you think is going to be different than what the next person thinks.  With a canonical style we don't need to worry about it any more and can focus our attention on things that matter more.

Comment: @zmb Accepted; but if the convention, for example, is to discourage same-line comments, then perhaps gofmt would do better by splitting them onto a new, preceding line. I also think code readability is probably one of the things that matter most, although, of course, readability is subjective. And, although we should definitely all adhere to standards, I think we *should* 'worry' about making them as good, and as fit-for-purpose, as possible.

Comment: Can't argue there.  FWIW, I don't think same line comments are discouraged, I just think your case of describing function args on separate lines was not optimized for.  Same line comments look fine otherwise: https://play.golang.org/p/JNpGqSD9Dz